# Удалить из строки рядом стоящие символы

Tags: java, строки

Нужно сделать из строки "aaaaabbbcccc dddddd" => "abc d". Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @vp_arth Людям, которые пришли из гугла, с тем же вопросом, не  интересует "работа это за автора" или нет. К сожалению, это достаточно часто встречающееся заблуждение о [целях сайта](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/23044), даже среди опытных участников. [Работа за автора](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String text = "aaaa111111111abbbccc........ dddddd";
    text = text.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
    System.out.println(text); //a1abc. d
}
```

Нашёл решение [здесь](http://kesh.kz/blog/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2/).

Comment: Стыдно, товарищ, отвечать таким вопросам.

Comment: @Other вы неверно представляете, [что полезно, а что нет на сайте](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044). Вот [комментарий к вам также относится](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625816/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b#comment875405_625816)

Comment: @jfs, это извечная проблема. И споры на эту тему не редки. Суть в том, что не смотря на желание создать "чистую и красивую бд знаний", главенствует тут трафик. А на чистоту плевать.

Answer (score 2):

Например, это можно сделать так:

```
String compact(final String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() < 2)
        return s;

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    char c = s.charAt(0);
    builder.append(c);
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char ci = s.charAt(i);
        if (c != ci) {
            c = ci;
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```